# Merging data frames by row names and making sure the rows are aligned

Tags: r, merge

This is an example code:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(3,4,5)
a_df <- as.data.frame(a)
b_df <- as.data.frame(b)
colnames(a_df) <- "Original"
colnames(b_df) <- "New"

total <- merge(x=a_df, y=b_df, by=0, all=TRUE)
```

When I run total, this is what I get:

```
  Row.names Original New
1         1        1   3
2         2        2   4
3         3        3   5
4         4        4  NA
5         5        5  NA
```

How can make total to look like this?

```
  Row.names Original New
1         1        1  NA
2         2        2  NA
3         3        3   3
4         4        4   4
5         5        5   5
```

SECOND EXAMPLE:

```
A <- c('c','d','f','k','j')
B <- c('d','k','j')
A_df <- as.data.frame(A)
B_df <- as.data.frame(B)
colnames(A_df) <- "Original"
colnames(B_df) <- "New"

total <- merge(x=A_df, y=B_df, by=0, all=TRUE)
```

Result:

```
  Row.names Original  New
1         1        c    d
2         2        d    k
3         3        f    j
4         4        k <NA>
5         5        j <NA>
```

What I am looking for is:

```
  Row.names Original  New
1         1        c <NA>
2         2        d    d
3         3        f <NA>
4         4        k    k
5         5        j    j
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The obtained output is correct. Element `3` in `b_df` has rowname `'1'`, as its the first element. The is matched to element `1` in `a_df`.
The 'missing' entries in `b_df` are row.names `4` and `5`.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I obtain a new output where both "3" in Original and New are on the same row? Similarly, all "4" are on the same row? Keep in mind that Original and New might contain character data, in which case all "c" should be on the same line, all "j" on the same line, etc...Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: You could match by columns, i.e. `match(a_df, b_df, by.x='Original', by.y='New', all.x=TRUE)`. But I have no idea what you mean with having all 'c', all 'j' on same row. Please update your question correspondingly.

Comment: Running 'match(a_df, b_df, by.x='Original', by.y='New', all.x=TRUE)' results in:   Original 1 2 3 4 5 -- which is not what I am looking for. I've updated the question to include more examples. Thank you!

Comment: You can do `row.names(B_df) <- match(B_df[[1]], A_df[[1]])` before your merge call, but I think using row names in this way is usually discouraged...

Comment: (My previous example should have been `merged(...)`, not `match`.

Comment: You are trying to use the row names of the data.frames as proxies for the columns you want to match. For the 'b' data.frames, the row names do not match what you want them to do. Print out both data frames, and look at what you want to match.

Comment: Frank, that works too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Original` and `New` as your matching variables but want to keep both variables in the resulting merged object, then one solution would be to create a new variable that you use for the merge.

Example 1:

```
a <- data.frame(Original = c(1,2,3,4,5))
b <- data.frame(New = c(3,4,5))

a$match = a$Original
b$match = b$New

merge(x=a, y=b, by="match", all=T)
```

Example 2:

```
A <- data.frame(Original = c('c','d','f','k','j'))
B <- data.frame(New = c('d','k','j'))

A$match = A$Original
B$match = B$New

merge(x=A, y=B, by="match", all=T)
```